# Remove element by reference

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

Using Wix Toolset (version 3.8) utility harvest to generate an installer xml file. We would like to use the xslt option to remove a folder with all its files and any reference to these files. The latter part of this is proving to be difficult;

Here is part of the xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALL_ROOT">
    <Directory Id="..." Name="MyCompany">
      <Directory Id=".." Name="doc">
        <Component Id="cmp20762D2CAD925E1B5974A3DD938BD5F3" Guid="..">
          <File Id=".." KeyPath="yes" Source="index.html" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp1BE839006D9CC9F26ECCBEE5894EFC33" Guid="...">
          <File Id=".." KeyPath="yes" Source="logo.jpg" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
   <ComponentGroup Id="Features">
    <ComponentRef Id="cmp20762D2CAD925E1B5974A3DD938BD5F3" />
    <ComponentRef Id="cmp1BE839006D9CC9F26ECCBEE5894EFC33" />
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Using this xslt I am able to remove the "doc" Dictionary including child elements but how do I remove the ComponentRef which refer to the child Component id attribute?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='doc']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following template to your stylesheet. It matches `ComponentRef` elements if there is a `Directory` element where the attribute `Name` corresponds to "doc" and the `Id` attributes are the same.

```
<xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[@Id = //wix:Directory[@Name='doc']/wix:Component/@Id]"/>
```

This removes both `ComponentRef` elements from your input XML since both of their IDs appear in `Directory[@Name='doc']`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="wix:Directory[@Name='doc']" />
   <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[@Id = //wix:Directory[@Name='doc']/wix:Component/@Id]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALL_ROOT">
         <Directory Id="..." Name="MyCompany"/>
      </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
   <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="Features"/>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score -3):

Thank you, that was very helpful

The final solution included double slash to handle a doc folder with subfolders.

```
   <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[@Id = //wix:Directory[@Name='doc']//wix:Component/@Id]"/
```

Comment: @user2936494: I see you have copied my solution to another answer. This is not very helpful on Stackoverflow. Instead, please leave a comment on my answer and accept it (mark the tick on the left) if it solved your problem.